# inner join on multiple tables in a DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, dataset, adodb

I have a data set which has 2 data tables.Both these tables are retrieved from 2 distinct Oracle Databases (physically and logically separate).

I need to do a Inner Join on these two tables which reside in 1 dataset. And then display the result in a gridview.

Are there any possibilities of doing SQL Joins on tables inside a Dataset?

If yes, does anyone have a worked out example? If not, can someone point me in the right direction - I do not wish to do any "hacks" (manually looping thru and other iterations of that sorts) as I believe there will be a way to do it within the environment, just need the right approach.

This is in VB .net so would appreciate a more relevant code BUT any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method helper:

```
private DataTable JoinDataTables(DataTable t1, DataTable t2, params Func<DataRow, DataRow, bool>[] joinOn)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataColumn col in t1.Columns)
    {
        if (result.Columns[col.ColumnName] == null)
            result.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
    }
    foreach (DataColumn col in t2.Columns)
    {
        if (result.Columns[col.ColumnName] == null)
            result.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
    }
    foreach (DataRow row1 in t1.Rows)
    {
        var joinRows = t2.AsEnumerable().Where(row2 =>
            {
                foreach (var parameter in joinOn)
                {
                    if (!parameter(row1, row2)) return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        foreach (DataRow fromRow in joinRows)
        {
            DataRow insertRow = result.NewRow();
            foreach (DataColumn col1 in t1.Columns)
            {
                insertRow[col1.ColumnName] = row1[col1.ColumnName];
            }
            foreach (DataColumn col2 in t2.Columns)
            {
                insertRow[col2.ColumnName] = fromRow[col2.ColumnName];
            }
            result.Rows.Add(insertRow);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go. I am using VB so will take me a little time to convert your piece to my requirements. How-ever is there no way of using something like "Datatables.Select" or something similar?